# Is file /etc/vfstab Solaris specific?

Tags: solaris, fhs

Is file /etc/vfstab Solaris specific. I mean it only exists in SunOS/Solaris and there is no such file in other UNIX-es/Linux/*BSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [`/etc/vfstab`](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vfstab) is used by *Solaris* but it is specific to all **SVR4** systems.

This is the equivalent of the [UNIX-es/Linux/*BSD `/etc/fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab). In fact the old *SunOS* 4.x was using `/etc/fstab` as well.

Here is a small list of known equivalent for `/etc/fstab` used by other proprietary OS:

- *IBM AIX* (3.x and 4.x): `/etc/filesystems`
- *HP-UX* (up to 9.x): `/etc/checklist`
- *Solaris* (since 2.x): `/etc/vfstab`
- *Sco Unix*: `/etc/vfstab`

**Edit**: fixing answer due to the underlying question (OS identification).

Comment: Thank you. My goal was to find a file which exists only in Solaris I'm going to use that file as hallmark for platform/OS detection.

Comment: What about other means to detect platform such as `uname` ?

Comment: There are plenty of them actually.

Comment: I just meant that basing your plaform/OS detection on specific files is maybe that wise (my 2 cents).

Comment: I agree with you. that is just a small part of the real case.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's the [SVR4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V#SVR4) standard location - it's just that Solaris is the most common SVR4 based OS remaining today.

If you look at [the Unix Rosetta stone](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) you will find `vfstab` was also used on other less well-known SVR4 based OS'es.

Comment: True. But I did not get at first what was the underlying question.